# Compute complex integral over circle

Tags: complex-analysis

> Compute the complex integral 
>   $$\oint_{C} \frac{e^{z}}{(z+\pi i)^3} dz$$
>   where $C$ is the circle with center at $0$ and radius $4$.

Here is my solution, and I hope I can get some correction
let $\gamma: \left[0,2\pi \right] \to \Bbb{C}$
with $\gamma (t)=4e^{it}$. Then 
$\gamma' (t)=4ie^{it}$ and
$$\oint_{C} f(z) dz = \int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{e^{4e^{it}}}{(4e^{it}+i\pi)^{3}} 4ie^{it} dt.$$
Let $\theta=4e^{it} $, then $ d\theta=4ie^{it}dt$, and 
$$=\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{e^{\theta}}{(\theta+i\pi)^{3}} 4ie^{it} \frac {d\theta}{4ie^{it}}=
\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{e^{\theta}}{(\theta+i\pi)^{3}} d\theta$$
Now I'm stuck here. Did I make some mistakes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not suggest to evaluate this integral directly.
Are you familiar with the [Residue Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem)?

In that case, since $|-\pi i|<4$, it follows that
$$I:=\oint_{|z|=4} \frac{e^{z}}{(z+\pi i)^3} dz=2\pi i\mbox{Res}\left(\frac{e^{z}}{(z+\pi i)^3},z=-\pi i\right).$$
Since the pole has order three then (see [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_(complex_analysis)#Simple_poles))
$$\mbox{Res}\left(\frac{e^{z}}{(z+\pi i)^3},z=-\pi i\right)=
\frac{1}{2!}\lim_{z\to -\pi i} (e^{z})''=\frac{e^{-\pi i}}{2}=-\frac{1}{2}.$$
Therefore $I=-\pi i$.

Another approach. By  [Cauchy Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem), the integral is equal to
$$I:=\oint_{|z+\pi |=r} \frac{e^{z}}{(z+\pi i)^3} dz=\oint_{|w|=r} \frac{e^{w-\pi i}}{w^3} dw=-\oint_{|w|=r} \frac{1+w+\frac{w^2}{2}+w^3h(w)}{w^3} dw$$
where $r>0$ and $h$ is holomorphic in $\mathbb{C}$. Again by [Cauchy Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem), $\oint_{|w|=r}h(w)dw=0$, hence
$$I:=-\oint_{|w|=r} \frac{dw}{w^3}-\oint_{|w|=r} \frac{dw}{w^2}-\frac{1}{2}\oint_{|w|=r} \frac{dw}{w}=0+0-\pi i=-\pi i$$
where in the last step we used the substitution $w=re^{it}$ with $t\in[0,2\pi]$.

P.S. BTW your substitution $[0,2\pi]\ni\theta=4e^{it}$ is not correct.

Comment: I have not learn about residue yet , so what is the correct one to being subtitute ? , by the way thanks for your respond

Comment: @Znik Dzulqarnain Do you know Cauchy theorem? See my edited answer. I am not able to evaluate it directly.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* Use [Cauchy's integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula):
$$
f^{(n)}(a) = \frac{n!}{2\pi i} \oint_\gamma \frac{f(z)}{(z-a)^{n+1}}\, dz
$$
with $f=\exp$, $a=-\pi i$, $n=2$.